# Replace HTML video with image on phone/tablet

Tags: php, mobile, html5-video

I have a looping, autoplay video on my homepage. When accessing my site from a phone or tablet, I'd like to have it replaced with a still image. I've tried a number of things but I am still having issues.

With the current PHP I am using, it works on an iPad, but not on my iPhone.

```
<?php
$tablet_browser = 0;
$mobile_browser = 0;

if (preg_match('/(tablet|ipad|playbook)|(android(?!.*(mobi|opera mini)))/i', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
    $tablet_browser++;
}

if (preg_match('/(up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|phone|android|iemobile)/i', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}

if ((strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']),'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml') > 0) or ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) or isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE'])))) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}

$mobile_ua = strtolower(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 0, 4));
$mobile_agents = array(
    'w3c ','acs-','alav','alca','amoi','audi','avan','benq','bird','blac',
    'blaz','brew','cell','cldc','cmd-','dang','doco','eric','hipt','inno',
    'ipaq','java','jigs','kddi','keji','leno','lg-c','lg-d','lg-g','lge-',
    'maui','maxo','midp','mits','mmef','mobi','mot-','moto','mwbp','nec-',
    'newt','noki','palm','pana','pant','phil','play','port','prox',
    'qwap','sage','sams','sany','sch-','sec-','send','seri','sgh-','shar',
    'sie-','siem','smal','smar','sony','sph-','symb','t-mo','teli','tim-',
    'tosh','tsm-','upg1','upsi','vk-v','voda','wap-','wapa','wapi','wapp',
    'wapr','webc','winw','winw','xda ','xda-');

if (in_array($mobile_ua,$mobile_agents)) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}

if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'opera mini') > 0) {
    $mobile_browser++;
    //Check for tablets on opera mini alternative headers
    $stock_ua = strtolower(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA'])?$_SERVER['HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA']:(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_DEVICE_STOCK_UA'])?$_SERVER['HTTP_DEVICE_STOCK_UA']:''));
    if (preg_match('/(tablet|ipad|playbook)|(android(?!.*mobile))/i', $stock_ua)) {
      $tablet_browser++;
    }
}

if ($tablet_browser > 0) {
   //tablet
   echo "
   <a id='button' style='background-position: center 6px!important; height: 80px;'></a>
   <img id='videoImage' src='videos/STILL-IMAGE.png'>";
}
else if ($mobile_browser > 0) {
    //phone
   echo "
   <a id='button' style='background-position: center 6px!important; height: 80px;'></a>
   <img id='videoImage' src='videos/STILL-IMAGE.png'>";
}
else {
   //everything else
   echo "
    <a id='button' style='background-position: center center; height: 69px;'></a>
    <video autoplay loop id='video'>
    <source src='videos/VIDEO.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
    </video>";
}   

?>
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working or have a different approach I can use to solve this?